# Tailwindcss paragraph <p> unexpected breakline when an element (svg) stand between the text

Tags: html, css, styles, tailwind-css

I'm using `Tailwindcss` to working with `nextjs`, I met a issue that recorded `<p>` tag **cannot contain any element in middle of the text**. It will breakline right before the element show up

It shouldn't breakline on the element on normal `<p>` tag. I disabled all the attribute can be find in the style console but it wasn't fix the problem. Only disable `base class` import in `tailwind.css` lead `<p>` run correctly, but it shouldn't be fixed like that

Comment: Not familiar with Tailwind, but can you put an `<img>` in the paragraph? The use the content of the svg in the img using a data src.

Comment: @MrLister I tried, same issue....

Comment: Please create a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Probably because  it's block. add `display:inline-block`  (`inline-block` class) to the inner element

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about "@tailwind base;" in application.tailwind.css? You shouldn't disable this as it might get issues in other designs.
Instead, what you can try is to wrap your text in the "span" tag and see whether it works. Hope I understood your question... For this, you'll have to use multiple span tags wrapping up your text only.